# download attribute on <a> not working (NOT cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

Observe the following code:

```
let cv = document.createElement('canvas');
cv.toBlob(blob => {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = 'test.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}, 'image/jpeg', 1);
```

If I open up the console on a new tab in my browser and paste this, it will download a file called `test.jpg` as expected. I have also done this on a variety of random websites (some on HTTPS, some on HTTP), and it worked everywhere. **However, if I try this on my own website, Chrome will load the image in the tab instead of downloading it.**

I am aware that the `download` attribute does not work with cross-domain URL's, but as you can see this is a `blob:` URL on the same domain. This behavior applies both to my test environment (which runs on `localhost:8585`) and my live website.

Now, I have read in the past that browsers sometimes treat `localhost` as cross-domain because it doesn't end in a valid TLD and therefore isn't a valid domain name (which would explain the bahvior on the test environment). My live website in turn has a `.app` TLD, which was introduced very recently -- so, the only explanation I can think of is that perhaps the browser doesn't yet recognize `.app` domains as valid, hence the cross-domain behavior.

Can anyone confirm my suspicion, or offer a solution?

Comment: On Chrome V68.0.3440.75 it works

Comment: @gaetanoM On a localhost site? The download itself works for me too in Chrome, just not on all origins.

Comment: Yes on localhost site (http://localhost:63342/...../file.html). Hence, I don't know where to look for.... As per your question I copied your code in my console, new page. Let me know if you have other info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but it only affect my live site and not the development/localhost environment. I'm not able to figure out why, exactly, but it seems consistent across different browsers which makes me think something is getting configured differently somewhere.

However, I did find a solution by reviewing the code in download.js which worked for my site.

It seems the key is adding a stopPropagation() call in the anchor's click event.

Add this right before appending the new element to the document.body:

```
a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
});
```